# Rails commands not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rubygems

I couldn't find anyone else with this problem so I thought I'd ask.

```
rails new myNewRailsApp
```

This works fine.

```
cd myNewRailsApp
ls
```

Reveals everything seems to have generated properly.

```
rails server
```

This creates a new directory "server" and creates a new rails application. It also seems to happen with "generate" and other command words. I'm on version 3.0.9 (considering rolling back now), and I purged it, all gems, and reinstalled. Am I missing something obvious?

Edit: I'm running on Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: It seems that your binary is rails 2.x, consider running `bundle exec rails server`.

Comment: just check `gem list` to see you don't have rails 2 installed. Also check your system packages to see, that you have not installed rails package from ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks as though it's using Rails 2 to generate a new app within your app. I've done this a few times and the amount of apps I've created with app names of "c" and "s".

To get round either use

```
bundle exec rails server
```

or

```
script/rails server
```

Or uninstall rails 2 from your system

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the command is still using 2.x version of rails. 
If you want to use multiple versions of rails for different projects use rvm to create gemset for each rails version.

[http://beginrescueend.com/][1]

If you dont want to use rvm, uninstall older versions of rails and try re-installing rails 3.x.